# How to get non-nil launchOptions when opening app by selecting an e-mailed file

Tags: ios, swift, uti

I have an app that has successfully been opening up a customized file type (.lprofile files) found in e-mails.  Now I want to be able to open another file type when the user taps on an attached file in an e-mail.  This is a binary data file, and it will have the extension .data on it.  When tapping on the file, it successfully opens the app, but I want to know the url of this file to be able to access and process it.  Unfortunately, the launchOptions dictionary in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is nil.  I'm assuming I've set something up wrong, but can't figure it out from articles online or other questions on this system.  I've attached a screenshot from the info.plist file.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if launchOptions != nil {

        urlOfMailedProfile = launchOptions![(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url as NSObject) as! UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey] as! URL?

        if urlOfMailedProfile != nil {
            if urlOfMailedProfile!.lastPathComponent == "data" {
                mailedEEPROMDataToBeRead = true
            }
            if urlOfMailedProfile!.lastPathComponent == "lprofile" {
                mailedProfileToBeRead = true
            }
        }

    } else {
        mailedProfileToBeRead = false
        mailedEEPROMDataToBeRead = false
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your direct question but the line `urlOfMailedProfile = launchOptions![(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url as NSObject) as! UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey] as! URL?` should be written as `urlOfMailedProfile = launchOptions?[.url] as? URL`.

Comment: You get the URL's extension using `pathExtension`, not `lastPathComponent`.

Comment: You should be doing all of this in the `application(_:open:options:)` delegate method. Your code won't be called if the app is already running when the users taps an email attachment.

Comment: @rmaddy:  Thx for the suggestions.  As for the third comment, there is no danger of this happening, because my app is set to not run in the background.

Comment: The option to avoid running in the background is going away soon. Time to update your app.

Comment: @rmaddy:  Trying to implement that application(_:open:options:), but it seems like maybe it is automatically opening the file asynchronously?  Processing of commands in this function happen AFTER it does all the setup for my first view controller.  I can deal with these issues, but the asynchronous process makes things messier.  What I really want is to just grab its URL and process it in my own way.  Is there any way to do this?  If not, I can find a way to make this work.  Thx for letting me know about the coming update.